# Input memory leaks in TIResourcePathManager

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I met a memory leaks problem when I using instrument to detect memory leaks in iPad device.

My device's default keyboard input is Chinese,Once I click the UITextField widget and after the keyboard is appeared the instruments get memory leaks.I wonder that if anyone met the same issue before? my device version is 6.1.

The following is the call tree from instrument output.

```
<i>UIApplication sendEvent<i>
<i>_NSOperationInternal start<i>
<i>NSBlockOperation main<i>
<i>TIResourcePathManager fetchAssetsWithNames:forInputModes:updatingDictionary:continuation  TextInput<i>
<i>TIResourcePathManager fetchAssetsWithNames:continuation TextInput<i>
<i>TIResourcePathManager fetchAssetsForQueryResults:withError:updatingArray:continuation: TextInput<i>
```

Comment: I have the same problem in simulator, but no problem in device. I think it's not a really problem.